# Serializing/Deserializing Singleton class or class with no default or no parameter constructor in java?

Tags: java, serialization

Can we serialize/deserialize a Singleton class or class with no default or no parameter constructor in java?

if not what is the way to do it?? will creating a no parameter protected constructor help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/71399/829571

Comment: Yes you can. It isn't the `Serializable` class that needs a no-args constructor, it is its nearest non-`Serializable` base class. See the Object Serialization Specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can not Serializing/Deserializing Classes only instances of classes

Answer (score 0):

You should create a proxy object for your Singleton and serialize it in the Singleton's stead.

You can read more about proxy serialization [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120104100009/http://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/08/10/serializing-immutable-singletons-serialization-proxy/).

Comment: This is not necessary. Poor quality third-arty citation.